# How to write CSS Style in RDLC Expression?

Tags: rdlc

I want create a underline for header with style.
How we can write css style in RDLC expression.
[image]

Comment: I am writting this in expression, but its not working, underline is not displayed on page.                                                                                                     ="<div style='text-align: center;'>Planning<br/><span style='display: block; border: none; color: #F59B00; height: 4px; background: #F59B00; background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 150, from(#F59B00), to(#fff)); background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at center, #F59B00 0%, #FFFFFF 50%);'></span></div>"